# How to create a player system?

Tags: python-3.x

i would like to create a Chess player system that returns either 1 or 0 corrosponding to the plauers turn, e.g. 1 being white, 0 being black.

here is what ive currently created:

```
def PlayerTurn(self):

    WhitePlayer = True
    BlackPlayer = False

    #while not TurnNotFinshed == False

    while True:
        if WhitePlayer == True:
            BlackPlayer == False
            print("White Players Turn!")
        elif BlackPlayer == True:
            WhitePlayer == False
            print("Black Players Turn!")
```

is there anyway in which i could possibly make this much better?

Comment: Consider starting on an easier project than a chess system

Comment: @Idos im mostly done, just need the player incremeting based on the turn.

Comment: If you have two boolean variables that are always supposed to be opposite of each other, consider only using one boolean variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an infinite loop there.  If you plan to play the whole game in that function, you should rename it to something like `PlayGame`.  I will assume you'll call the function once per turn, and the only reason for the loop is in case the user entered illegal input and you're retrying it.

Here's a way to do what you're doing above.

```
class Chessgame:
    white_turn = False
    def PlayerTurn(self):
        self.white_turn = not self.white_turn
        done = False
        while not done:
            if self.white_turn:
                print("White Player's turn")
            else
                print("Black Player's turn")
            ... logic to get and verify player's input here ...
            done = True
```

But that doesn't do what you asked, which is a function to return 0 or 1 based on whose turn it is.  Here's code that allows you to call a function to tell you whose turn it is (but without 0 or 1), and you can call that function any number of times, with another function to advance to the next player:

```
class Chessgame:
    turn = 1
    def whiteTurn(self):
        return (self.turn & 1) == 1

    def endTurn(self):
        turn += 1
```

`whiteTurn` returns True if it's white's turn, or False if it's black's turn.  Call `endTurn()` whenever the current player's turn is over.  (`turn & 1` evaluates to 1 if turn is odd, zero otherwise.  `&` is the bitwise AND operator.)

Another improvement would be to have Player objects, like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color

    def __str__(self):
        return self.color

class Chessgame:
    players = (Player("white"), Player("black"))
    turn = 0

    def player(self):
        return self.players[self.turn & 1]

    def endTurn(self):
        print("Turn over for", self.player())
        self.turn += 1
        print("Turn starts for", self.player())
```

I wouldn't actually put the print statements in `endTurn()` but provided them to show you how the player object can be used.